# All conformal maps from $\mathbb{H} $ to $\mathbb{D}$ are of the form $\frac{e^{i\theta}(z-\beta)}{z-\overline{\beta}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $\theta \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in \mathbb{H},$ it is clear that $z \in \mathbb{H} \longmapsto e^{i\theta}\dfrac{z-\beta}{z-\overline{\beta}} \in \mathbb{D}$ is conformal. On the proof to the converse, I read that it suffices to find a known conformal map $G:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$, then all conformal maps $F:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$ is of the form of $F=f \circ G,$ where $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is conformal.    May I know why it is so? Or is there a more appropriate way to establish the converse?

Thank you.

Comment: May I know the meaning of the notation $\Bbb H,\Bbb D$..

Comment: I think $\Bbb H=\{\Im z>0\}$ and $\Bbb D=\{|z|<1\}$.

Comment: @user152715: See Joe's reply.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point is that the composition of conformal (= biholomorphic) maps is again conformal. So if $F_1,F_2 \colon \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$ are conformal, then

$$f = F_2\circ F_1^{-1}\colon \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$$

is conformal, i.e. an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$, and $F_2 = f \circ F_1$. Conversely, if $F_1\colon \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$ is conformal, and $f$ an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$, then $F_2 = f\circ F_1\colon \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$ is also conformal.

So you obtain the set of all conformal maps $\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$ by composing one of them with the set (group) of automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$, that is, for any $F\in \operatorname{Con}(\mathbb{H},\mathbb{D})$, we have a bijection

$$\varphi_F \colon \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D}) \to \operatorname{Con}(\mathbb{H},\mathbb{D})$$

(where $\operatorname{Con}(U,V)$ denotes the set of conformal maps $U\to V$).

If one knows the automorphism group of $\mathbb{D}$ - in particular that it consists only of Möbius transformations - then one knows that the set of conformal maps from the upper half-plane to the unit disk also consists only of Möbius transformations, if one knows that it contains one Möbius transformation. The latter is readily verified, and further, one easily sees that any two conformal maps from the half-plane to the unit disk which map the same point - $\beta$, say - to $0$ differ only by a rotation, which gives the specified form $e^{i\theta}\frac{z-\beta}{z-\overline{\beta}}$.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Fischer:

Thank you. Here is my attempt: Let $F : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$ be a conformal map and $F^{-1}(0)= \beta.$ Define $f:\mathbb{\mathbb{H}} \to \mathbb{D}$ by $f(z)=\dfrac{i-z}{i+z}.$  Let $k=f(\beta).$  Also,  define $\psi_{k}: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ by $\psi_k(z)=\dfrac{k-z}{1-\overline{k}z}.$

Hence, $g:=\psi_{k}\circ f \circ F^{-1}: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is conformal. Apply Schwarz lemma to $g,g^{\prime},$ we have $|g^{\prime}(0)| \leq 1$ and $ |(g^{-1})^{\prime}(0)|\leq 1.$ Since $|g^{\prime}(0)||(g^{-1})^{\prime}(0)|=1,$ we have $|g^{\prime}(0)|=1. $ Again, by Schwarz Lemma, $g(z)=e^{i\theta}z,$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}.$ So, $F(z) = e^{-i\theta}\dfrac{k-\frac{i-z}{i+z}}{1-\overline{k}\frac{i-z}{i+z}} \ ? $

Comment: Upon simplification, I will get $F(z) = v\dfrac{z- w}{z-\overline{w}},$ where $w= \dfrac{k-1}{1+k}$ and $v=-\dfrac{k-1}{1-\overline{k}}e^{-i\theta}$

Comment: Yes, that's right. (You forgot to mention that $g(0) = 0$ for the application of the Schwarz lemma.) Now you can, if you wish, manipulate the expression for $F(z)$ to get the form $e^{i\varphi}\frac{z-\beta}{z-\overline{\beta}}$.

Comment: Noted! I have posted another question here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960550/if-the-real-part-of-f-is-bounded-above-by-a-in-the-unit-disk-then-fz
but I don't quite understand the hint provided. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Consider the map $w \mapsto \frac{w}{w-2A}$ there. See how that gets you to Schwarz and the desired estimate.

Comment: Thank you. Let $g: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $g(w)=\frac{w}{w-2A}.$ Then, $g$ is conformal? Since $g^{-1} \circ f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ and $g^{-1}(f(0))=0,$ by Schwarz lemma, $|-2Af(z) | \leq |z||1-f(z)|, \forall z\in \mathbb{D} \ ?$

Comment: No, the other way round. That maps the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} w < A$ conformally to the unit disk. So $g\circ f \colon \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $(g\circ f)(0) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Apply to Schwarz lemma to $g \circ f,$ we have $|f(z)| \leq |z||f(z)-2A|$

Comment: That doesn't work so easily, unfortunately. But you then know that $f(z) = g^{-1}(\rho\cdot z)$ for some $\rho$ (depending on $z$) with $\lvert \rho\rvert \leqslant 1$. Now you can estimate $\lvert g^{-1}(u)\rvert$.

Comment: $\dfrac{|f(z)|}{|f(z)-2A|} \leq |z| < 1 \implies \dfrac{\left|\dfrac{f(z)}{f(z)-2A}\right|}{1-\left|\dfrac{f}{f(z)-2A}\right|} \leq \dfrac{|z|}{1-|z|}$
$ \implies |f(z)| \leq \dfrac{|z|}{1-|z|}\left(|f(z)-2A|-|f(z)|\right) \leq \dfrac{2A|z|}{1-|z|}$

Comment: Yup, that works too. Didn't think of that way.